# To bypass CORS restrictions in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors

We are trying to develop a chrome extension for some of our API's to help some nontechnical users. As expected we are facing CORS. There are a few options left with us to use our plugin

```
 1. Disable the chrome security manually
 2. Install a third party plugin
```

Both these were turned down (:). Is there a way to include this feature in our custom extension? References to any documentation for this would be helpful.

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found that by adding a proper permission section (with some regx matching) in the manifest file can solve our problem.

Thanks,
San